# Flash Hit Test Object as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Ok I need help to figure out how to make it when the stuntman collides with the hoop it adds one point but instead it detects the collision multiple times and adds 5 points.Thanks for the help.
This is my code:

```
stop();

// Variables to increase money

var totalmoney = 0;

var moneygain:int = 1;

var moneylimit:int = 100000;


//on collision with hoop add 1 point to money

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, HoopCollision);

function HoopCollision(event:Event):void
{
  if(startstuntman.hitTestObject(starthoop))
  {
    totalmoney += moneygain;
  }
  Total.text = totalmoney;
  trace("HIT");
}
```

Comment: on the first hit, I'd set a flag to not allow another hit for x amount of seconds or milliseconds and then a timeout that resets that flag. You would then test for the hit && if the flag is true

Comment: Another option is to move startstuntman after the hit if your code allows.

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you're having difficulty with?  If all you wanted was `totalmoney += 5`, you could simply change `var moneygain:int = 1` to `var moneygain:int = 5`.  I must be misunderstanding your question to believe such a thing could be the issue.

Comment: I don't want it to add 5 point I want it to add 1 point, but it detects it multiple times.I want it to add only 1 point.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to ***dynamically add attribute*** by adding:

```
stop();
    
var totalmoney = 0;

var moneygain:int = 1;

var moneylimit:int = 100000;

starthoop["hit"] = new Boolean(false); // *** initial is not hit by startstuntman ***


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, HoopCollision);

function HoopCollision(event:Event):void
{
  if(startstuntman.hitTestObject(starthoop) && starthoop.hit == false) // *** checking additional expression ***
  {
    totalmoney += moneygain;
    starthoop.hit = true; // *** starthoop is now hit, so next time it checks, it wont increase totalmoney because of additional expression***
  }
  Total.text = totalmoney;
  trace("HIT");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I don't know if the code is written to repeat itself multiple times but I need my code to repeat every time. If i have confused you I am sorry I will try to elaborate.                                          I have this code working on a motion tween that repeats itself, what I want it to do is that when the motion tween collides with the hoop I want it to detect the collision once every time it goes through the hoop. While this code is helpful it doesn't repeat the code every time. If it helps my code goes to frame 32. Thanks.